# Dynamic URL's with multible layers

Tags: django, django-urls

Im making a website using Django, where im making dynamic URLs. However i'm fairly new to programming and haven't been able to find out how to make dynamic URLs with more than 1 parametre.

I'm making a site called "kartotek", which are user specific defined by the varible "kl_id", and therefore has a dynamic URL with following path:

`path('kartotek/<str:kl_id>/', views.kartotek, name="kartotek"),`

On this page, is there a button with which you choose a patient and come to another URL called "reg" with the following path:
   `path('reg/<str:kl_id>/<str:pt_id>/', views.reg, name="reg"),`

I have the following code in views.py:

```
def kartotek(request, kl_id):
    kliniknavn = Klinik.objects.get(navn=kl_id)
    E_patient = kliniknavn.patient_set.all()
    context = { 'kliniknavn':kliniknavn, 'E_patient':E_patient}
    return render(request,'DentHelp/kartotek.html', context )

def reg(request ,kl_id , pt_id):
    kliniknavn = Klinik.objects.get(navn=kl_id)
    ptid = Patient.objects.get(id_nr=pt_id)
    context = {'ptid':ptid, 'kliniknavn':kliniknavn}
    return render(request,'DentHelp/reg.html', context)
```

I think the problem is the template code, which I'm kinda confused how to make, I was trying this:

```
{% for patient in E_patient %}
<a href="{% url 'reg' klinik.navn, patient.id_nr %}" class="btn btn-primary">Vælg patient</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Any have an advise?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try assigning values explicitly to the appropriate attribute names, like so:

```
href="{% url 'reg' kl_id=klinik.navn, pt_id=patient.id_nr %}
```